# Windows remembering lower case filename, how to force it to forget?

Tags: windows, svn

Here's my problem:

I've got source files I'm publishing (.dita files, publishing using Oxygen) and I need to change capitalization on a lot of them, along with folders and subfolders that they're in. Everything is in source control using SVN.

When I change only an initial cap, say, and leave everything about the filename the same otherwise, Windows "remembers" the lower case name, and that's what gets published, even though the source name is now upper case.

I can even search for the filename, for example Foobar.dita, and the search results will show me "foobar.dita". When I go to that location directly in the file explorer, the file is named Foobar.dita. It's  not a duplicate, it's the same file.

What I understand from reading up on this is that Windows isn't case-sensitive, but it "remembers" the filename as one case or the other. So my question is, if I can't force Windows to be case-sensitive, can I somehow force Windows to forget the filename? I've tried deleting it from both Windows and SVN, and recreating it, but it still gets read as lower case when it's initial cap.

If I rename the file, even slightly, it solves the problem, but many of the filenames are just what they need to be, and it's a lot more work to rename them (to think of another good filename) than just to change to initial cap.

UPDATE:

[Here's where I read](https://superuser.com/questions/266110/how-do-you-make-windows-7-fully-case-sensitive-with-respect-to-the-filesystem) about about the "remembering" idea, in response two, the one with 7 recommendations.

To be explicit: I'm not updating from SVN and thus turning it back to lower case, it's upper case in SVN. It appears upper case in the Windows folder.

UPDATE II: This seems to be what I'm up against:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625

> In NTFS, you can create unique file names, stored in the same directory, that differ only in case. For example, the following filenames can coexist in one directory on an NTFS volume:
>   CASE.TXT
>   case.txt
>   case.TXT
>   However, if you attempt to open one of these files in a Win32 application, such as Notepad, you would only have access to one of the files, regardless of the case of the filename you type in the Open File dialog box.

So it sounds like the only answer is rename the files, not just change case.

Comment: Rename (`svn mv`) in case-sensitive OS Working Copy?!

Comment: Windows isn't case-sensitive, so it doesn't "remember" anything. "Test.txt" is the same as "test.txt", which is the same as "teST.TXT". Renaming a file to what is essentially the same name does nothing. It's SVN that is case-sensitive; you have to use it to rename the files.

Comment: Ken: No, I am using SVN to rename them. If I rename using SVN > rename, then commit the changes to the SVN repository, now I have a file named "Foobar" in Windows Explorer. If I publish from there, I get "foobar". If I search for the file, using Windows, I get results showing "foobar". When I click on that lower-case result listing to go to the file location, it's named "Foobar" viewed directly in the Windows folder. See update in my post for the info about "remembering". Maybe it's incorrect. Thx